# VB: Filter linq query with a list

Tags: vb.net, linq

so I'm new to LINQ and a just made a test query from a csv file that displays its results in a data grid. I was using simple Where statements like Where sys = "System 1" without a problem. When it came to multiple where tests where I didn't know how many systems I would be checking against I got stuck.

How should I set up the where to check against a list?

```
Where listSystems.Contains(sys)
```

Is what I thought should work but it returns no results.

Full Code

```
Dim lstSystem As New List(Of String)

lstSystem.Items.Add("System 1")
lstSystem.Items.Add("System 4")
lstSystem.Items.Add("System 5")
lstSystem.Items.Add("System 7")

 Dim Test As String() = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("test.csv")
 Dim query = From item In Test
             Let data = item.Split(","c)
             Let name = data(0)
             Let sys = data(1)
             Let price = data(2)
             Where lstSystem.Contains(sys)
             Order By name, sys, price Ascending
             Select name, sys, price
    dgvResults.DataSource = query.ToList
    dgvResults.CurrentCell = Nothing
    dgvResults.Columns("name").HeaderText = "Name"
    dgvResults.Columns("sys").HeaderText = "System"
    dgvResults.Columns("price").HeaderText = "Price"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this in console. I faked Test with dummy data, as I don't know what is in your CSV file:

```
    Dim lstSystem As New List(Of String)

    lstSystem.Add("System 1")
    lstSystem.Add("System 4")
    lstSystem.Add("System 5")
    lstSystem.Add("System 7")


    Dim Test As New List(Of String) From {"1,System 1,2", "4,System 5,6", "7,8,9"}
    Dim query = From item In Test
                Let data = item.Split(",")
                Let name = data(0)
                Let sys = data(1)
                Let price = data(2)
                Where lstSystem.Any(Function(x) x = sys)
                Select New With {.Name = name, .System = sys, .Price = price}
    For Each i In query
        Console.WriteLine(i.System)
    Next
    Console.ReadLine()
```

Comment: Thank you! Where lstSystem.Any(Function(x) sys.Contains(x)) did it!